# with <div> whitespaces </div> innerHTML is <div>whitespace</div> in internet explorer, there's a way to get the exact content of a textnode?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, cross-browser

if you try this:

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.appendChild(document.createTextNode("    te      st    ");
alert('-->' + x.innerHTML + '<--');
```

ie6-7-8 will alert

```
'te st '
```

ie9-10 and others browsers:

```
'    te      st    '
```

there is a way to fix this behavior in older IEs?

thank you

p.s. I don't want to use < pre >

Comment: Darn, I was about to whip out `pre`.

Comment: I tested your code by IETester, and both IE6 & IE7 alert the same as FF does : "-->    te      st    <--". How weird??? Btw, your code needs a "close parenthese" at the end of line 2, right before the semi-colon ";"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to fix this in older IE if the white space is not rendered (using a `<pre>` element or CSS `white-space: pre`). Unrendered white space characters are simply not part of the DOM in those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var x = document.createElement("div");
x.appendChild(document.createTextNode("    te      st    ".replace(' ','&nbsp;'));
alert('-->' + x.innerHTML + '<--');
```

Comment: Is better to use .replaceAll(' ', '&nbsp;')

Answer (score 0):

Not having IE to test it but have you tried x.textContent ?

Btw these white space are "stripped" from the browsers when they render the content so why exactly do you need them?

Comment: I've tried innerText textContent nodeValue .firstChild.nodeValue .firstChild.data but no way to get the original string... btw there are alternatives to do what i'm trying to do, now it's just a personal challenge against internet explorer xD